# Can't show BLOB from php myadmin in UIImageView

Tags: android, iphone, image, base64, blobs

We are using some images in our app from our database. We are putting them to `BLOB` via encoding to `base64`, and then getting by decoding. The problem is, that all images we are putting from android app, we are getting normally to android app, but NULL to iPhone app. However, all images we are putting from iPhone app, getting from DB normally for both: iPhone and android app. Maybe it's not same library of `Base64`? Why this is happening? Any idea?

Comment: please use dots(.) after the completion of a sentence.here it is so difficult to understand what are you saying.

Comment: so confused after read your query.:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing library of Base64 solve my problem! If somebody have the same problem, get library of Base64 from  [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64/)